# Are watts consumed in wireless electricity?

Tags: power, wireless, watts, electricity

If I put a transistor on a coil of wire connected to a 120v AC circuit, and made it so my toaster was now wirelessly powered, if I turned the toaster on would it consume watts that are able to be measured on my wattmeter?

Comment: That power has to come from somewhere.

Comment: Portable power is still power, even if it is RFID which is 'broadcasted' power.

Answer (score 4):

You won't create a wireless power transfer system in the manner you have described. It will take rather more engineering than that.

If, however, you were to create a proper wireless charging system then the power the taken from the mains would be the power drawn by the toaster + all the losses in your system. The cost of your wireless toast is given by the formula:

$$ \$ Toast_{wireless} = \frac {\$Toast_{mains}}{Efficiency} $$

so wireless toast will be more expensive than wired toast. If your efficiency is 80% then the wireless toast costs 1.25 times that of mains toast.

It can't be any other way. Your toaster requires energy. The energy has to be generated somehow - and generally paid for.

> ... if I turned the toaster on would it consume watts that are able to be measured on my wattmeter?

Yes.